# Why can't I dominate certain law enforcement?

Tags: payday-2

I'm trying to understand how you can effectively dominate a SWAT/FBI/whatever law enforcement in payday 2, because only certain ones are "able" to be dominated. which confuses me, how is this determined?

Also, I already know that tasers and higher can't be dominated, but the question is for the weaker forces, regular SWAT/FBI and guards.

Anyone on this list of law enforcement: http://payday.wikia.com/wiki/Enemies_%28Payday_2%29

The further down the list you go, obviously the harder it is to dominate them, but what determines this? Is there any clue to try to dominate a specific one instead getting myself killed trying to do so.

Comment: Guards are all created equally.  You are allowed one dominated guard per played after 4 are dominated it won't work.  Also you can't dominate after a shot is fired at them.

Comment: I'm really just trying to get an answer that doesn't say its random, because i don't think anything in games is ever random, they just might seem random, but they normally work under some kind of formula/algorithm.

Comment: The skill is chance based... Does that help?

Comment: @Ramhound which means it's random xd

Comment: @Sickest Ever heard of an RNG? There is a massive number of things in games that are random... Really not sure where you got otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Domination has a complex set of conditions and multipliers that affect your chances, and there is a state and duration combination that is very similar to shouting down civilians.  [The Long Guide](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=267214370) has a section, "Domination," just after the ones on stealth.  It's a long section, but well worth reading.

**During stealth**, if you shout at them (and have Domination skill) within **1.5 seconds** of alerting, you will succeed.

**Out of stealth**, an enemy will never surrender if he is at **full health** and **not reloading**.

Answer (score 1):

It's random. If you have the skill dominator from the mastermind tree, you can dominate in stealth like 99% of the time. While you're already seen and the alarm has been set off, it's alot harder.

[image]

- The further down the list you go, obviously the harder it is to
  dominate them, but what determines this? Is there any clue to try to
  dominate a specific one instead getting myself killed trying to do
  so.

the tactic everyone uses is just shoot him with a bullet till he really stops shooting and then try it again. Do this over and over again. There isn't a clue to try to dominate a specific one.

Comment: thats not true, i have those perks and its not 99% of the time whats so ever. It's not even close to 99%, more like 10% with FBI / Swat.

Comment: Depends if they have been shot at.  Your current question only says guards not FBI/SWAT...

Comment: @Ramhound Yeah which counts as most stealth missions. Thats why I say 99%. Guards are like very easy. There isn't a real specific chance.

Comment: @Sickest FBI? FBI isn't hard to dominate... You mean the ones from firestarter day 2? Swat isn't even there when in stealth.

Comment: Well... the question has changed from guards to "Certain law enforcement"

Comment: The original question mentions "Tasers and higher", which gives away that he meant all law enforcement by "guards", you just need to make a slight adjustment to the answer.

Comment: @3ventic His question stated: `Also, i already know that Tasers and higher can't be dominated, but the question is for the weaker forces` So it's not about the tasers and highers.

Comment: An FBI and guard and special "Taser" are all different.  Only the actual guards are guards...only Non-specials can be dominated

Comment: @ramhound FBI(IF he means the one from firestarter day 2) and guards(From banks and juwelry's) are easily the same to dominate. Also police officers really feel the same to me.

Comment: http://payday.wikia.com/wiki/Enemies_%28Payday_2%29

Comment: @Sickest Aha well sorry I went for the thing I remembered the best... Thanks anyway.

Comment: That page is wrong you can only dominate and cuff 1 guard per player

Comment: @Ramhound Can you please use @ username so people know you are talking to them. Now he wont be notified

Comment: No; his user name is to much of a pain to type on a phone; also my last comment applies to all

Comment: @ramhound You can actually dominate a guard, joker him, and dominate another, that would be 2 dominated guards, i didn't read the page just merely pointed it out to show the FBI agents in the game for Loko.

Comment: @Sickest I editted the answer to answer your main question.

Comment: Try aiming while you dominate.